# Python - Работа с путем к файлу состоящий из переменных и текста

Tags: python, cmd

Есть отрывок кода:

```
cmdpath = os.path.join(root, file) #В переменную уже заложен путь к cmd.exe
with open('test.txt', 'wb',0) as file:
    subprocess.run(r''cmdpath+' /C arp -a', stdout = file, check = True)
```

Вопрос: как корректно указать в команде  subprocess.run путь к файлу и последующую
команду к cmd.exe если путь указан в cmdpath чтобы команда была фактически равна:

```
subprocess.run(r'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C arp -a', stdout = file, check = True)
```

Comment: Зачем вам запускать именно `cmd`? Что особенного он должен сделать? Если вам нужно запустить `arp.exe` с нужными параметрами вы можете сделать это напрямую: `subprocess.run(['arp', '-a'])`

Comment: Честно говоря даже не знаю. Но и к arp.exe нужно указывать путь.

Comment: Не нужно указывать путь - для системных утилит этот путь уже указан в специальной глобальной переменной внутри ОС (`PATH`) - вам остается только вызвать бинарник по его названию, без указания пути.

Comment: @m9_psy Спасибо, в силу не опытности не знал.

Comment: cmd.exe вам не нужен здесь, как [явно показано в моём ответе на ваш прошлый вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651195/23044)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
cmdpath = os.path.join(root, file) #В переменную уже заложен путь к cmd.exe
with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
    cmd = Popen(cmdpath, shell=True, stdout=file, stdin=PIPE)
    cmd.stdin.write('arp -a\n'.encode())
    cmd.stdin.close()
```