# Python Взаимодействие с cmd.exe

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess

Необходимо вызвать командную стоку Windows, отправить команду (например `ipconfig`).
Затем полученный результат сохранить в Notepad.

Пробовал через pywinauto/subprocess. Дальше вывода cmd экрана продвинуться не смог.

Как можно реализовать, или в каком направлении искать?

Comment: Может [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on) решит вашу проблему

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Чтобы получить результат команды как строку, не обязательно `cmd.exe` вызывать, можно напрямую запустить дочерний процесс:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output('ipconfig')
```

Чтобы "сохранить в notepad", просто в файл пишите результат:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path('~/output.txt').expanduser().write_bytes(output)
```

Вместо приведённого пути (сохраняет файл `output.txt` в домашнюю директорию пользователя), можно специфичную для программы директорию использовать ([текущую рабочую директорию или путь относительно скрипта или что `appdirs` модуль возвращает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044)).

Можно за один шаг: вызывать команду и сохранить её результат в файл сразу:

```
with Path('~/output.txt').expanduser().open('wb', 0) as file:
    subprocess.run('ipconfig', stdout=file, check=True)
```

См. [Python - Запуск cmd.exe с аргументом, и последующим сохранением ответа в .txt файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651195/23044)

Чтобы сохранить вывод, используя другую кодировку (к примеру, [если вы кракозябры видите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)), необходимо декодировать  вывод программы в Unicode, а затем сохранить в кодировке, которую понимает ваше окружение:

```
import ctypes
import os

encoding = os.device_encoding(1) or ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetOEMCP()
text = subprocess.check_output('ipconfig', encoding=encoding)
```

[Byte при печати вывода внешней команды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497719/23044).

После этого в желаемой кодировке можно сохранить. К примеру, по умолчанию используется `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` кодировка:

```
Path('~/output.txt').expanduser().write_text(text)
```

вы можете в `write_text()` другую кодировку передать (к примеру, `encoding='utf-8'`).

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Бьюсь с кодировкой вывода)

Comment: @m_dig: поэтому необходимо декодировать вывод программы в Unicode. Я из уже приведённой ссылки на другой ответ одно из решений прямо в текущий ответ вставил. Если это не будет в вашем случае работать, то нажмите на ссылку и там ответ прочитайте.

Answer (score 6):

```
os.system("ipconfig >some-file.txt")
```

Comment: А можно как-то минусы пояснить?

Comment: код  может вести  к кракозябрам. Код запускает shell (%COMSPEC%) без необходимости: другой синтаксис и пути поиска программы  — изменение пути к результату может требовать экранирования пути и прямого редактирования строки  — если папка из недоверенного источника, приходится думать о shell injection. Документация рекомендует использование subprocess модуля вместо этой функции.

Comment: @jfs, про кракозябры не понял, а с остальным вроде согласен для общего случая.

Comment: нажмите в моём ответе на слово кракозябры и увидете, что это такое

Comment: @jfs, где они должны возникнуть и почему? Весь вывод запускаемой программы перенаправляется в файл, соответственно полушится нормальный текстовый файл (вероятно, в кодировке 866). На каком этапе что-то должно пойти не так?

Comment: что вы думаете вы увидите открыв в notepad этот файл?

Comment: @jfs, не знаю насчёт notepad'а, но NPP кодировку определит. В любом случае, это не проблема файла. К тому же, не уверен, что ipconfig выводит что-то на кириллице.

Comment: у вас может и нет проблемы, а [автора есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793223/python-%d0%92%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-cmd-exe/793236#comment1250716_793227) и автор именно про "сохранить в notepad" спрашивал. На Windows, ANSI cp подразумевается для Windows приложений (когда Unicode не используется), а не OEM (пережиток dos). [Код автора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/793567/23044) как раз и занимается преобразованием OEM (для выбранного окружения) в ANSI (Windows code page).

Answer (score 1):

Большое спасибо за помощь. 
Получившийся работающий код:

```
def ipconf_cmd():
   text = subprocess.check_output('ipconfig')
   decoded = text.decode('cp866')
   Path('~/output.txt').expanduser().write_text(decoded)
```

Comment: decode здесь не нужен. Просто encoding передайте как показано в моём ответе. Жёстко не прописывайте кодировку иначе кракозябры можно получить. Какое значение для encoding на вашей машине код из моего ответа выводит?