# Можно ли с помощью модуля OS передавать сразу две последовательные команды в командную строку?(Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd

Хочу что бы при выполнении определенного условия запускалась консоль и автоматически предавались 2 команды по очереди .
Такое можно реализовать с модулем **OS**? Или нужны дополнительные модули? **Подскажите пожалуйста.**

Comment: Используйте `subprocess`, надо дубликат поискать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python - Запуск cmd.exe с аргументом, и последующим сохранением ответа в .txt файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650101/python-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-cmd-exe-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-txt-%d1%84%d0%b0)

Comment: Я посмотрел тот вариант который мне предложили. И у меня появился другой вопрос

Comment: Примите дубликат на этот и задайте новый вопрос

Comment: Я уже отказал и поменял суть немного. Извените

Comment: Два раза сделайте то, что написано в том вопросе... Предвосхишая следующие вопросы — сделайте N раз

Comment: Благодарю, а как с помощью команды cd переместиться на рабочий стол? какой путь указывать?

Comment: `C:\Users\Имя пользователя\Desktop`, если не ошибаюсь (сейчас не на винде)

Comment: Да как раз в это время я решил посмотреть свойства)))

Comment: File "d:/prog/PYTHON/Python/os/test.py", line 2
    os.startfile(r'c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe', 'cd C:\Users\clash\OneDrive\Рабочий стол')
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 5-6: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape Выдает такую ошибку(

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос с отформатированным кодом и ошибкой