# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 5-6: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Возникает такая ошибка. В такой программе:

```
import os 
os.startfile(r'c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe', 'cd C:\Users\clash\OneDrive\Рабочий стол')
os.startfile(r'c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe', 'attrib +h +s +r lol')
```

Comment: Попробуйте `r` перед всеми строками поставить

Comment: После того как я и перед командами поставил возникла другая ошибка Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: OSError: [WinError 1155] Указанному файлу не сопоставлено ни одно приложение для выполнения данной операции: 'c:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe' так жке вот такая

Comment: что мне делать?

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/650101/python-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-cmd-exe-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-txt-%d1%84%d0%b0) вам подойдет `os.system`

Comment: спасибо, но проблема теперь в другом

Comment: Не надо использовать `os.system()` или `os.startfile()`, когда есть поддержка этого в самом Питоне (его основных библиотеках).